Не находит нужный объект с помощью API, а по той же строке поиска в Яндекс картах находит
Требуется программно определить район туристического маршрута в Республике Карелия по его описанию в заявке. В заявке указано:

Место начала маршрута: База" Адмирал" Харвиа

Если задать такую строку в поиске непосредственно Яндекс, то в результатах несколько ссылок на эту базу отдыха в Республике Карелия, Лахденпохский район.
Если же я задаю строку поиска через api со следующим значением geocode:

geocode="База «Адмирал» Харвиа"

то результат содержит только ссылку на один объект в Вологодской области с названием
"Посёлок база"
Как правильно составить запрос, чтобы получить ссылку на объект в Карелии?

Результат поисковой строки карт Яндекса выводит результат работы поискового api, но не api геокодирования. Скорее всего находится адрес этой базы и он в свою очередь отправляется геокодеру. Также поисковый запрос нормализуется и очищается перед токенизацией.
Попробуйте:

Нормализовать адрес из вашего запроса (убрать кавычки сокращения и пр.);
Найти дополнительные части адреса и отправьте в запросе.



Есть ли возможность обращения к поисковому api?  2.Если ограничить зону поиска, скажем по bbox, то вероятно не найдёт ничего. 3. Я думал , что возможно необходимо использовать какие то
специальные символы типа "+","%"


У меня не находит именно базу Адмирал при поиске База «Адмирал» Харвиа  на yandex maps. Даже при поиске просто в яндексе находится яхт клуб Адмирал. Но он в Петрозаводске, а не в Харвиа. Доп. символы ставить не нужно. Слова и так должны токенизироваться по пробелу.

Спасибо!  Не сразу заметил. Показывает ещё домик в Харвия - это то же место, это отвлекло. Видимо, они неудачно указали место начала и окончания маршрута, по крайней мере Яндексу неизвестное. Обычно указывают координаты хоть одной точки, по ней сразу определяется. В данной заявке по regex можно найти район.
